# Ruby on Rails: Add a check box for each value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I am trying to display checkboxes on a form that show all of the contacts for a user, so that the user can then select the contacts required. I have done this on the form so far, which displays the checkboxes but with no value:

```
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
        <% if contact.user.id == User.find(session[:user_id]).id %>
            <%= f.check_box :to %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But when I try to change the line `<%= f.check_box :to %>` to `<%= f.check_box :to, contact.email %>` to show the email address of the contact I get the error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "email@123.com":String
```

Is there a way around this? I have looked at multiple posts before and tried various options but none seem to help, including:

[Ruby on rails f.label for a check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232115/ruby-on-rails-f-label-for-a-check-box)
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes
[How to add a checkbox for each row in Rails 3.2 index page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073223/how-to-add-a-checkbox-for-each-row-in-rails-3-2-index-page)

Comment: solved by chumakoff, who explained that I needed to change an array to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much logic in the view. I can't see your code, but I can give you some recommendations:

In the controller:

```
@contacts_of_current_user = @contacts.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
```

View:

```
<% @contacts_of_current_user.each do |contact| %>
      <%= f.label :to, contact.email %>
          <%= f.check_box :to, {}, contact.email %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Edit

From the comments I understood that you need to get a string of chosen emails.

There are two ways you can do it.

1) Somehow build this string on the client side (JavaScript)

2) Or pass an array of emails and then concatenate them into single string on the server

I can show you how you can pass an array:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:to, @contacts, :email, :email ) %>
```

Or you can do it manually, something like this:

```
  <% @contacts_of_current_user.each do |contact| %>
      <%= f.label :to, contact.email %>
          <%= check_box_tag 'to[]', contact.email %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that still doesn't work

Comment: What do you need to pass in the `contact[to]` parameter?

Comment: I need to pass the email address, hence why I am trying contact.email in the above

Comment: Do you want to get an array of emails? Or a few emails as one string?

Comment: kind of, what my aim is is for a user to select say 4 email addresses and then these email addresses get concatenated into one and saved in the database, e.g. "1@a.com;2@b.com;3@c.com;4@d.com"

Comment: In time I will plan on splitting these out, so one record for "1@a.com", then another for "2@b.com", etc.

Comment: Again, thanks, but `<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:to, @contacts, :email, :email ) %>` shows the email addresses but when one is ticked and I click "submit" it is not saved in the database - for the record the email address field is blank

Comment: I need more code to understand what you need. You can easily do it by yourself. See in the log what parameters you get and what is wrong. I gave you base recommendations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118924/discussion-between-ben-smith-and-chumakoff).